# How to filter multiple values using BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with numbers and values. Each number has several values.
I want to get list of numbers where no one negative value.

```
SELECT 1 as id, 10 as number, 0.2 as value
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 10, 0.3
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 10, 0.4
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 10, 0.4
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 11, 0.3
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 11, -0.3
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 11, 0.1
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 12, 0.83
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 12, 0.16
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 12, 2.3
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 12, 0.3
```

I this case I need to get numbers 10 and 12 only because one value of number 11 is negative.
I know how to make it using `EXCEPT` statement. Maybe there is some more effective way, because original table has more than 70 millions rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT number
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY number
HAVING COUNTIF(value < 0) = 0
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use an aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT number
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY number
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN value < 0 THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Comment: `SUM` not supports `BOOL` argument. It's does not work

Comment: Check the updated version which uses a `CASE` expression.